# Want to Group data by Supplement name, Category etc. in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table named supplement, now i want to Group the data in it by following column names: sup_cat,sup_sub_cat,sup_name etc.
And if their are two rows of a similar sup_cat,sup_sub_cat,sup_name then total quantity and selling quantity should be added together.

Data Example:

1. Protein Whey Protein ON Gold Standard Whey Protein 100
2. Protein Whey Protein ON Gold Standard Whey Protein 50
3. Protein Isolate Protein ON Isolate Protein 100

Then it should show as :

1. Protein Whey Protein ON Gold Standard Whey Protein 150
2. Protein Isolate Protein ON Isolate Protein 100

Table structure is as follows:
[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Just use `group by` at the bottom with all those columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use group by like following:

```
SELECT sup_cat,sup_sub_cat,sup_name, sum(sup_qty), sum(selled_ty)
FROM supplement
GROUP BY sup_cat,sup_sub_cat,sup_name;
```

Comment: @MandeepSingh, Then please mark it as accepted one so that other people will get help from it in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by to aggregate value for a particular group

```
select sup_cat,sup_sub_cat,sup_name, sum(qty) Quantity, sum(Sale) Sales
from supplement
group by sup_cat,sup_sub_cat,sup_name;
```